# Eclipse + OpenCV + Cygwin --> cv.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, eclipse, opencv

Hi I'm having troubles in Eclipse including OpenCV Library. I Follow a lot of tutorials but i can't compile anything. Here is the output from the console.

```
Building file: ../hand.c
Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler
gcc -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"hand.d" -MT"hand.d" -o"hand.o" "../hand.c"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: D:\Eclipse_workspace_C++\HelloWorld\Default
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/Eclipse_workspace_C++/HelloWorld/Default
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
../hand.c:3:16: fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target `hand.o' failed
make: *** [hand.o] Error 1
```

I'm using OpenCV2.0.

I configured in proyect properties the C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings Tab -> Compiler and Linker to add library and headers of opencv but i can not compile it.

ScreenShoot of my eclipse project.

[image]

Comment: Do the following checks 1) have you included "../include/opecv" and "../include/opencv2" paths? 2) check for Environmental variables for both opencv and cygwin are properly set.

Comment: Hi, environmental variables are set. About include opencv2? i haven't this folder in the opencv 2.0 directory.

Comment: y cant you use opencv4+ versions? why sticking with 2.0?

Comment: I'm trying with the last one but i get the same result...using 2.4.5

Comment: Ok, but now i get the same problem with D:\opencv\opencv2.4.5\build\include\opencv/cv.h:63:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
subdir.mk:21: recipe for target `TestOpenCV.o' failed, see current image in question

Comment: Ok, I faced the same issue. And at that time my problem is "make.exe". I changed the "make.exe" and worked gr8. But I dont that might help you!

Comment: Thanks @2vision2, finally i've got it working.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!

Steps for configure Eclipse and OpenCV 2.4.5 in Windows

1) after installing Opencv include in environment path your directory where opencv is installed, mine is opencv\opencv2.4.5\build\include

2) I use Cygwin to compile c files. So configure your eclipse using CDT for Cygwin and in project setting put next configuration.

[image: Settings Compiler]

[image: Settings Linker]

if you are using mingw put there in linker settings. For me it's only vc9.

3)My source file is like

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include <cv.h>

    int main(void) {
        puts("Hello World!!!");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Can you compile any of openCV source files, such as: #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 IplImage* img1 = cvLoadImage("lenna.png");
 cvShowImage("MyWindow1", img1 );

 cv::Mat img2;
 cv::imread("lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

 cv::namedWindow("MyWindow2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 cv::imshow("MyWindow2", img2);

 cvWaitKey(0);
 return 0;
}

Comment: Have you included the folders opencv and opencv2 to the project and binaries to the path?